# express.js 4 and sockets with express router

Tags: express, socket.io

I'm trying to create a really simple node API using express.js 4 but I need a few 'realtime' events for which I added socket.io.  I'm fairly new to both so I'm likely missing something basic but I can't find good docs/tuts on this.

In the express app (created with the express generator) I have something like this based on simple examples and project docs that I read.  This works OK and from client apps, I can send/receive the socket events:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var api = require('./routes/api');
var app = express();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(3000));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/api', api);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('client connect');
    socket.on('echo', function (data) {
        io.sockets.emit('message', data);
    });
});


// error handlers omitted

module.exports = app;
```

but I want to use the sockets from my API routes (in the ./routes/api.js file that I 'require' above).  For example, someone might use the API to PUT/POST a resource and I want that broadcast to connected socket.io clients.

I cannot see how to use the 'io' variable or organise the code currently in the `io.sockets.on('connection' ...` function inside express routes.  Here's the `./routes/api.js` file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var io = ???;

router.put('/foo', function(req, res) {
    /* 
      do stuff to update the foo resource 
      ...
     */

    // now broadcast the updated foo..
    io.sockets.emit('update', foo); // how?
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've modified your files a little bit, may you check if it works?

You can pass the io you've defined to your routes like below;

```
require('./routes/api')(app,io);
```

I didn't test the Socket.IO parts but there is no syntax error and routes also working.

server.js file:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(3000));
 
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
 
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('client connect');
    socket.on('echo', function (data) {
    io.sockets.emit('message', data);
 });
});

require('./routes/api')(app,io); 
 
console.log("Server listening at port 3000");
```

api.js:

```js
module.exports = function(app,io) {
app.put('/foo', function(req, res) {
 
    /* 
 
      do stuff to update the foo resource 
 
      ...
 
     */
 
 
    // now broadcast the updated foo..
    
    console.log("PUT OK!");
 
    io.sockets.emit('update'); // how?
    res.json({result: "update sent over IO"});
 
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks Caner. That works and with a couple of minor tweaks I could use that since this particular app is fairly simple.  But as I'm trying to use it to learn some best practices too, is there a way to continue using the express Router()?   That seems to be the idiomatic way to go for express 4.x.

Comment: @darrend, according to express.js documents it looks it is okay to use like that http://expressjs.com/api.html , what do you think?

Comment: It's reasonable - I'll mark as accepted and dig into the docs and code some more.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Update for people: I found a lot cleaner solution by Logan Tegman http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872317/express-4-routes-using-socket-io

Comment: Hey @cdagli, I tried it. But it says, `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
`.

Comment: Is it ok from an arhitectural point of view to mix the express REST API with websockets? Refering to app.put() method

Answer (score 39):

One option is to pass it in to req object.

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var api = require('./routes/api');
var app = express();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(3000));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('client connect');
    socket.on('echo', function (data) {
        io.sockets.emit('message', data);
    });
});

// Make io accessible to our router
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.io = io;
    next();
});

app.use('/api', api);

// error handlers omitted

module.exports = app;
```

./routes/api.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.put('/foo', function(req, res) {
    /* 
      do stuff to update the foo resource 
      ...
     */

    // now broadcast the updated foo..
    req.io.sockets.emit('update', foo); 
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: did you actually get the above code to work? the io on my request keeps showing as undefined in my router code

Comment: ups I had a mistake there - the part `// Make io accessible to our router` should be defined before `app.use('/api', api);`

Comment: Adding a small 2021 update, for v4 of the library. To import the library use `import { Server as socketsIOServer } from 'socket.io';`. To connect the sockets' server to your express server use `const io = new socketsIOServer(app.listen(...));`. The rest works exactly the same

Answer (score 3):

Supposing you want to access the SocketIO from anywhere in your application, not just in the router, you could create a singleton for it. This is what works for me:

```js
//socket-singletion.js

var socket = require('socket.io');

var SocketSingleton = (function() {
  this.io = null;
  this.configure = function(server) {
    this.io = socket(server);
  }

  return this;
})();

module.exports = SocketSingleton;
```

Then, you need to configure it using your server:

```js
//server config file

var SocketSingleton = require('./socket-singleton');
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
SocketSingleton.configure(server); // <--here
server.listen('3000');
```

Finally, use it wherever you want:

```js
//router/index.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var SocketSingleton = require('../socket-singleton');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    SocketSingleton.io.emit('news', {msg: 'success!'});
  }, 3000);
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: In your solution, this keyword in socket-singletion.js remains undefined at the time of initialization.

Comment: @abhishake are you using arrow functions? if so, "this" will behave differently and it will probably not work as described above

Answer (score 1):

One more option is to use [req.app](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.app).

#### app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const logger = require('morgan');
const api = require('./routes/api');

const app = express();
const io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(3000));

// Keep the io instance
app.io = io;

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// ...

app.use('/api', api);

module.exports = app;
```

#### routes/api.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.put('/foo', function(req, res) {
    /*
     * API
     */

    // Broadcast the updated foo..
    req.app.io.sockets.emit('update', foo);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think best way is to set io as a property of req, like below:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.io = io;
    next();
});

app.use('/your-sub-link', your-router);
```

Answer (score 1):

Refactored [Edudjr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52437432/11125430)'s answer.

Change the singleton to create a new instance of socket.io server

```
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const singleton = (() => {
    this.configure = (server) => this.io = new Server(server)
    return this
})();

module.exports = singleton
```

Initialise your express app, the server and the singleton.

```
// initialise app
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);

// configure socket.io
socket.configure(server)
```

Then in your router

```
const socket = require('/utils/socket-singleton');

socket.io.emit('event', {message: 'your message here'})
```