# How to use socket.io with node js rest api?

Tags: node.js, rest, socket.io

I want to build a web application with node js rest api as backend and angular 4 as frontend. I want to use socket io for real time. How to use socket io with node js rest api?

Comment: websockets => rest api , wont work try sending Ajax requests

Comment: This is far too generic and non-specific an answer for us to know what you're trying to accomplish or do.  Please describe exactly what you are trying to do with socket.io and how that has anything to do with a rest api and we can then maybe offer some advice.  As your question stands now, it will likely be closed as either "unclear what you're asking" or "too broad".

Comment: Checkout this link:
https://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4

Comment: @jfriend00 I want to get the data from server using REST api, but I want it to be real time. So I want to use socket io.

Comment: Well, you have to decide if you want to get the data via REST or via socket.io.  Pick one of the other.  Your REST server can allow socket.io connections and then a client can connect to it on socket.io and then you can send data to the client over socket.io.  Still not sure what your question is.

Comment: Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334800/express-js-4-and-sockets-with-express-router) it might be useful for you

Answer (score 1):

So I was looking for a discussion about this, but I just implemented something and I wanted to share and see if I can get any feedback. I think socket.io is a great way to implement APIs, especially for bidirectional communication, and realtime communication. Here's a start:

On the server side created this file - socket-api-server:

```
"use strict";

const serverIo = require("socket.io");
const server = serverIo.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000);

const api_keys=JSON.parse(process.env.SOCKET_API_KEYS|| "[]");

/**
 * Server Side
 * 
 */

function socketAPIServer(apis){
    server.on("connection", (socket) => {
        // this must be first - to block unauthenticated access to the APIs
        socket.use((packet,next)=>{
            if(socket.auth) return next();
            else if(packet[0]==="authenticate" && api_keys.includes(packet[1])){ 
                socket.auth=true;
                socket.emit("authenticated")
                return next();
            }
            else return next(new Error("unauthorized"));
        })
        socket.on("disconnect", () => {
            delete socket.auth;
        });
        apis.forEach(api=>{
            socket.on(api.name,api.func)
        })
    });
}

module.exports=socketAPIServer;
```

Then I have API's in a file - but you could do them as separate files:

```
const APIs=[
    {   name: "api_name", func: (p1, p2,..., cb)=>{
            cb(figure out what to send )
        }
    },
    {   name: "another_api_name", func: (p1,cb)=>{
            cb( calculate something from p1)
        }
    }
];

socketAPIServer(APIs);
```

Then on the client side I have a file that looks like this:

```
const clientIo = require("socket.io-client");

// ensure ENV keys
if (!process.env.API_KEY) {
    console.error("API_KEY needed.  On bash use: export API_KEY=\"your-key-here\" or add it to your .bashrc file")
    process.exit();
}

// ensure ENV keys
if (!process.env.API_URL) {
    console.error("API_URL needed.  On bash use: export API_URL=\"your-key-here\" or add it to your .bashrc file")
    process.exit();
}

const ioClient = clientIo.connect(process.env.API_URL);
var authenticated=false;
var queued=[];

ioClient.on('connect',()=>{
    console.info("client connected", ioClient.id);
    ioClient.emit('authenticate', process.env.API_KEY);
    ioClient.on("authenticated",()=>{
        authenticated=true;
        while(queued.length) queued.shift()();
    })
});

function socketAPI(...args) {
    if(args[0]==='disconnect') 
        return ioClient.close();
    if(!authenticated) queued.push(()=>ioClient.emit(...args))
    else
        ioClient.emit(...args)
}

module.exports=socketAPI;
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
    var socketAPI=require('./socketAPI');

    socketAPI("api_name",p1,p2,results=>{
        console.info(results);
    })
```

for testing set

```
export API_URL="http://localhost:8000" 
export API_KEY="a long random string"
export API_KEYS="[\"a long random string\"]"
```

This could probably be expanded on, but it's a start.  Please let me know if this is useful, or if there is somewhere this kind of discussion is happening. 
:-)

Answer (score 0):

web sockets come in handy when you want to have real-time interactive communication. Means that you want a full duplex communication. 
usage:
npm i socket.io

```
io.on('connection', socket => {socket.emit('request', /* … */); // emit an event tothe socketio.emit('broadcast', /* … */); // emit an event to all connected socketssocket.on('reply', () => { /* … */ }); // listen to the event});
```

https://socket.io/docs